# Jquery ajax autocomplete calling a method for data

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

```
$(function () {
        $("#tbNominalAccounts").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response){
                $.ajax({
                url: "TestPage3.aspx/GetUserNominalAccounts",
                type:"POST",
                datatype:"json",
                data :{ searchText : request.term},
                success: function(data) 
                {
                    response(
                        $.map(data, function(item)
                    {
                        return { label: item.NominalAccount, value:item.NominalAccount, id:item.NominalAccount}
                    }))
                }
            })
            }
        });

    });
```

Added breakpoints and it hits the ajax call but when i put a breakpoint on the method `GetUserNominalAccounts` it doesent even reach it!! Any ideas of why its not posting?!

I have a textbox with an ID of `#tbNominalAccounts` just for background information

Comment: Can you share the exact error you see in Firebug or the chrome console? That will make it easier to diagnose and help you.

Comment: What does the browser console, or Fiddler say?

Comment: it says post to 'GetUserNominalAccounts' is unauthorised

Comment: Also I assume you are using webforms?

Comment: asp.net includes webforms and mvc - so is it webforms or mvc?

Comment: i think it doesent like my jquery.min.js file, it breaks on line 17, will an updated version fix this?

Comment: its definitely webforms because were not using mvc yet

Comment: what is the `response(` line there ? is it another out side function ?

Comment: can you do "TestPage3.aspx/GetUserNominalAccounts" should it be "TestPage3.aspx?paramName=GetUserNominalAccounts" instead??

Comment: Post your server side code for review - likely it is not properly decorated to allow access from a web page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reformat your data like so:

```
pString = '{"searchText":"' + request.term + '"}';
    $.ajax({
        data: pString,
...
```

and your **server side code should have been properly "decorated" to allow page access**.

Thought I would add some code from a working sample using asp.net: you might need this converter for generic handling of the asp.net data:

```
dataType: "jsond",
type: "POST",
contentType: "application/json",
converters: {
    "json jsond": function(msg)
    {
        return msg.hasOwnProperty('d') ? msg.d : msg;
    }
},
```

EDIT: And for the use of the return value:

```
focus: function(event, ui)
{
  return false; // return "true" will put the value (label) from the selection in the field used to type
},
```

Comment: thanks its hitting the method now, only problem is that its taking to long to retrieve the records, when i put a break tag in my return statement it shows thousands of the records but it doesent show in my textbox! any ideas on this?!

Comment: You should put something in place server side to limit number of the rows returned, sorted on your preference and limiting to a match of ONLY the text in the searchText value.

Comment: it still wont write out to the textbox, in my serverside code, ive got 'return lstnominalAccounts.ToList();' when i hover over it ive got the records and i can scroll through them but it wont output to the textbox any ideas

Comment: Does this output ANYTHING? or just a limited number/count?

Comment: it filters what i write into the textbox but doesent out put a drop down or anything else, just when i hover over my return statement it shows everything relating to what i typed in my textbox. Its this that i want in the textbox!!

Answer (score 0):

try putting a contentType in the ajaxRequest:

```
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
```

I've noticed that when using jQuery Ajax the default content Type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` doesn't work well enough.